# How to use the difference between two lists to transform the first into the second? Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a large number of identical lists 'old' which I want to transform in the same way into a list 'new'. The way I want to do it, is to make an example of the desired list 'new'. Then I turn the difference between the two lists 'old' and 'new' into a rule, and then use that rule to turn my other lists 'old_2' into 'new_2'.

I cannot figure out how to do the first step and the second step does not give me the expected result. Is there an elegant way to do this?

```
import numpy
        # 0    1    2    3    4    5
old_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
new = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A']

# 01 Get the difference new - /- old_1 based on index positions of
# the list elements, to get something like this:

order = [1,2,3,4,0]

# 02 Then use this order to transform a second identical list, old_2.
# For this I wanted to use the following: 

old_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
old_2 = numpy.array(old_2)
order = numpy.array(order)
inds = order.argsort()
print('inds =', inds) # As a check, this gives the wrong order: [4 1 0 2 3]
new_2 = old_2[inds]

# I expected this to result in what I want, which is:
print(new_2)
['C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'A']

# But what I get in reality is this:
inds = [4 1 0 2 3]
['E' 'B' 'A' 'C' 'D']
```

Any suggestions to get the desired result?

```
  new_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A']
```

Comment: Does `old_1` array is unique array?

Comment: Not necessarily. A or B might appear twice. But new_1 will (of course) only contain elements that are in old_1, but could contain less elements than old_1.

Comment: If A or B occur more than one time then there could be multiple solutions of `order `. How would you decide which one to select?

Comment: Very good point ... Only the elements in the first 2-3 positions will change locations (either to the very end or they will be distributed). And these first 2-3 are different from each other. The other elements in the sequence will stay in the same order. I have revised the example based on your point.

Comment: The variable 'order' contains index positions, which are of course unique.

Comment: Is `order = [2,1,3,4,0]` correct?  These are the index of element from old in new, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167296/discussion-between-sumit-jha-and-twhale).

Comment: It was not, I have corrected it to the new example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, I tried to edit your code. Hopefully it helps.

```
import numpy as np

def get_order(new, old):
    order = []
    for element in new:
        order.append(old.index(element))
    return order


def main():
    old_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    new = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A']

    order = get_order(new, old_1)
    print(order)

    old_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    old_2 = np.array(old_2)
    order = np.array(order)
    #inds = order.argsort()
    #print('inds =', inds) # As a check, this gives the wrong order: [4 1 0 2 3]
    new_2 = old_2[order]
    print(new_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
['B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'A']
```